# On controlArray.push(new FormGroup) unable to enable() the previous form group control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am facing issue regarding a scenario say.

When I add a new control to array using `controlArray.push(new FormGroup)`, I am unable to use `enable()` for the previous form group control as `STATUS`  is "VALID" always where as if I don't push any new `FormGroup` I am able to edit status to 'DISABLED' using disable(). I need to actually edit my initial form group controls along with new one added.

Please guide me with a way!

```js
const controlArray = this.editPostForm.get('formArrayName') as FormArray;
controlArray.push(
  this.fb.group({
    id: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
    authors: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
    metaData: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }))
  })
);
toggleEdit(i) {
const controlArray = this.editPostForm.get('formArrayName') as FormArray;
controlArray.controls[i].enable();
}

Fields are enabled for editing.But on pushing same form group again toggleEdit() for previous form group controls doesnt not enable fields.
Control Array for previous formGroup always retains Status to be "VALID' and enabled = 'true' although my fields are enabled onclick toggleEdit()
```

Comment: can you please add some code of your formGroup?

Comment: const controlArray = this.editPostForm.get('formArrayName') as FormArray;
controlArray.push(this.fb.group({
  id: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
  authors: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
  metaData: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }))
}));

Comment: so what you want to disable on it?

Comment: actually when i push form group for first time and use controlArray.controls[i].enable(); this it changes my status of controlarray from DISABLED to VALID, which make all my entries enabled to be edited, but second push, my first control array status is always VALID and never DISABLED which restricts my fields to enabled for editing. But i can edit my second time Pushed control array.

Comment: i still dont understand. so you controlArray was disabled at first time? please add the descriptions and more in your question

Comment: :) can you add the code into question, not as a comment? just edit the question